# Messagebox simulator

Tags: windows, gratis, user-interface, screenshot

I am looking for a program than lets me configure a standard Windows message box dialog and then shows it so I can take a screenshot of it.

- must support icons
- must support buttons
- must support multiline text

Optional:

- copy screenshot to clipboard directly
- save screenshot as file

Use cases:

- requirements engineering: define what shall happen
- testing / QA: provide example of potential enhancement

Answer (score 1):

Probably overkill, but by far the easier way to create this would be getting [Delphi Starter edition](https://www.embarcadero.com/app-development-tools-store/delphi) (free for new users) and just create a new project, then drop your buttons and components on the new form, then press F9.

In order to get a standard Windows dialog, you can use some code:

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  MessageDlg('Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed ' +
    'do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ' +
    'ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut ' +
    'aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit ' +
    'in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. ' +
    'Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui ' +
    'officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.',
    mtConfirmation, mbYesAllNoAllCancel, 0);
end;
```

[image]

Comment: I am looking for the messagebox layout. If I drop buttons on a form, it does not necessarily look like a messagebox.

Comment: You are right. If you want to show the _actual_ result (using Windows functionality) you may need to add a couple of lines of code. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: Well, I have Visual Studio, so I can write a MsgBox() call there. It's not the kind of solution I'm looking for.

Comment: Ah, well. Posted my edit before seeing your comment.

Comment: I've never seen a "No to all" and "Yes to all" button on a default message box.

Comment: @Thomas there you have one

Comment: I prefer to install [Gexperts](http://www.gexperts.org/) into Delphi and use that to create my messge boxes.

Answer (score 0):

If you install [Python 2.7](https://www.python.org/downloads/) and [wxPython 3](https://wxpython.org/download.php#msw) plus the [Docs and Demos Suite](https://wxpython.org/download.php#msw) then this will give you, from within the Demo program the ability to create just about any native control that you need. *Note that Python 3 support is on the way with the Phoenix build but currently more complex to install.*

- Free, gratis & open source
- Cross platform but gives native controls on each platform
- All of the Demos are editable from within the Demo.
- Icons, Buttons & Multiline Text all supported.
- Great for prototyping *and for production* UIs
- As you can see there are lots of other controls that you can customise.

A custom message box in seconds:
[image: MsgBOx]

The Demo window with the code customisation going on:
[image: Demo]